# Prove existence of invariant subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$V$ is a $4$ dimensional vector space over the field of real numbers. $T$ is a linear operator on $V$. Prove that there is a proper non zero invariant subspace of $V$ under $T$.

If $T$ has a characteristic value, then the corresponding characteristic space is invariant under $T$.

Otherwise, the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is a product of $2$ irreducible polynomials of degree $2$.

What do I do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T$ has an eigenvalue , then we are done.

For otherwise,

fix a non zero $v \in V$. Consider $\{v,Tv,T^2v,T^3v,T^4v\}$. This set is linearly dependent, so $\exists$ scalars $a_0,...,a_4$ not all zero such that $$a_0v+a_1Tv+\cdots+a_4T^4v=0$$

But $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4$ can be written as

$$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4=k(x^2+\alpha_1x+\beta_1)(x^2+\alpha_2x+\beta_2)$$

Then $$0=k (T^2+\alpha_1T+\beta_1)(T^2+\alpha_2T+\beta_2)$$

So $T^2+\alpha_iT+\beta_iI$ is not $1-1$ for $i=1$ or $2$. Consequently $\exists$ non zero $u$ so that $$T^2u+\alpha_iTu+\beta_iu=0$$

Then $\text{span}(u,Tu)$  is invariant  under $T$(Check!)

Comment: thanks. I have understood.